# How to get IP address in Pascal

Tags: delphi, networking, ip, pascal

i am getting these two Errors trying to view IP address and show in a messagebox

Error looks like this

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(38): E2010 Incompatible types: 'PAnsiChar' and
> 'PWideChar'  => Error1

and

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(40): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and
> 'array[1..1024] of Byte' => Error2

I could do this in C/C++ but i wanted to try something new in Delphi

My source code Looks like this

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Wininet, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    hInet: HINTERNET;
    hFile: HINTERNET;
    buffer: array[1..1024] of byte;
    bytesRead: DWORD;
    url : String;

begin
  url := 'https://icanhazip.com';
  hInet := InternetOpen(PChar(application.title),INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,nil,nil,0);
  hFile := InternetOpenUrlA(hInet, PChar(url), nil, 0, 0, 0); //Error 1
  InternetReadFile(hFile,@buffer,SizeOf(buffer),bytesRead); // Error 2
  showmessage(buffer);

end;

end.
```

Please what am I doing wrongly?

**Edit**

Okay, `InternetOpenUrl` Worked,however , it still gives me error on the showmessage(buffer)

Code looks like this now

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Wininet, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    hInet: HINTERNET;
    hFile: HINTERNET;
    buffer: array[1..1024] of byte;
    bytesRead: DWORD;
    url : String;

begin
  url := 'https://icanhazip.com';
  hInet := InternetOpen(PChar(application.title),INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,nil,nil,0);
  hFile := InternetOpenUrl(hInet, PChar(url), nil, 0, 0, 0);
  InternetReadFile(hFile,@buffer,SizeOf(buffer),bytesRead);
  showmessage(buffer);

end;

end.
```

**Edit2**

My code Looks like this now

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Wininet, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    hInet: HINTERNET;
    hFile: HINTERNET;
    buffer: String;
    bytesRead: DWORD;
    url : String;
    szMessage : String;
    i : integer;


begin
  //url := 'https://icanhazip.com';
  hInet := InternetOpen(PChar(application.title),INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,nil,nil,0);
  hFile := InternetOpenUrl(hInet, PChar('https://icanhazip.com'), nil, 0, 0, 0);
  InternetReadFile(hFile,@buffer,SizeOf(buffer),bytesRead);

  //showmessage(buffer);
  Label1.Caption := buffer;

end;

end.
```

Comment: Please add the Delphi version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error happens because you call the AnsiChar version of the function.

Use `InternetOpenUrl` instead of `InternetOpenUrlA`.

The second happens in the line below you expect it. *ShowMessage* expects a `string` and not an `array of byte`.

**Edit:**
To get a string out of your array of bytes to be passed to ShowMessage, you need to know in what encoding the bytes are sent. Assuming that is UTF-8, the conversion can simply be done with:

```
ShowMessage(TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Slice(buffer, bytesRead)))
```

**Edit 2:**
OK, for XE8 you have to do a bit more work.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    hInet: HINTERNET;
    hFile: HINTERNET;
    buffer: TBytes;
    bytesRead: DWORD;
    url : String;

begin
  url := 'https://icanhazip.com';
  hInet := InternetOpen(PChar(application.title),INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,nil,nil,0);
  hFile := InternetOpenUrl(hInet, PChar(url), nil, 0, 0, 0);
  SetLength(buffer, 1024);
  InternetReadFile(hFile,@buffer[0],Length(buffer),bytesRead);
  showmessage(TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead));    
end;
```

Comment: thanks Uwe. InternetOpenUrl worked, its now the showmessage(buffer) , still gives me Errors

Comment: lemme update Code.

Comment: changing to string returns access violation. Let me show you what my code looks like this time

Comment: See my edit to this answer for an example to convert bytes to string.

Comment: it returns this as error sir [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(45): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'GetString' that can be called with these arguments

Comment: That's why I asked for the Delphi version you are using. If nothing is specified I always assume the latest.

Comment: Delphi XE8 is the delphi version

Comment: I added an example for XE8

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ you typically use a NUL terminated string -and allocate the storage to hold that string yourself.  This is what you have done in your code with the BYTE array.

In Delphi a `string` is a native type, not just a pointer to NUL terminated character data.

From the Error message you provided the error happens on the call to ShowMessage, not on the call to InternetReadFile.

You need to pass a string variable to ShowMessage.

You could try this:

```
var
  szMessage: String;
  i: Integer;

  SetLength(szMessage, bytesread);
  for i =1 to bytesread do
    szMessage[i]:=buffer[i-1];
  ShowMessage(szMessage);
```

There are ways you can do this more compactly, but as someone who has moved from C++ to mainly using Delphi these days I think looking at the operation this way helps to understand the differences between the two languages.